# :host equivalent in component.ts

Tags: angular

In `component.css` you can access `<component>` tag with `:host` selector.
Is there a direct way to access it in `component.ts` file?

I am aware of using `ViewChild` and `parentElement`, is there a more direct way of getting host DOM element?

Comment: What is `parentElement`?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject it

```
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement...
  }
}
```

Comment: That was a lot easier than I thought. Thanks

Comment: why `constructor(this.elRef:ElementRef) {}` instead of `constructor(elRef:ElementRef) {}`?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed it up with Dart syntax. With `private`(instead of `this.` it becomes a field available from `ngAfterViewInit` and elsewhere within the class.